# How can I convert wbemtest result to vbscript?

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to create a vbs code which outputs "sNodeType" parameter. Can someone please help me with th code? See the screenshots of wbemtest below.

[image: Namespace]

[image: Object and method]

[image: Parameter]

Edit:

I got some progress. I have managed to execute the method with no errors. But I couldn't figure out how to get the value of out parameter "sNodeType" in this method. Here is my code:

```
strComputer = "."
strNamespace = "root\Honeywell"
strClass = "TPS_Config"
strMethod = "GetNodeType"

Set oClass = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\" & strNamespace)
Set oMethodExec = oClass.ExecMethod(strClass, strMethod)

WScript.Echo oMethodExec.ReturnValue
```

Comment: Helps if you read [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/swbemservices-execmethod) - *"If the method is successful, an `SWbemObject` object is returned."*. So you `oMethodExec` will contain an `SWbemObject`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't realize that I have already did it.

Just typed `WScript.Echo oMethodExec.sNodeType` and VOILA!